# styleClass property of SelectItem in PrimeNG multiselect

Tags: css, primeng, multi-select

Can anyone explain me how to use `styleClass` of `SelectItem` interface of PrimeNG ?

I am using PrimeNG multiselect and I think styleClass for each SelectItem is used to apply a class on that particular element. But somehow not able to do so.

Code snippet below:

**HTML**

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1" optionLabel="label"></p-multiSelect>
```

**sample.ts**

```
    cities1: SelectItem[];
this.cities1 = [
        {label:'New York', value: 'New York', styleClass: 'testClass'},
        {label:'Rome', value: 'Rome'},
    ];
```

Now I expect for the first element of dropdown to have class *testClass*. But it's just not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use templating functionality for that.

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1" optionLabel="label">
    <ng-template let-city pTemplate="item">
        <span [ngClass]="city.value.styleClass">{{city.label}}</span>
    </ng-template>
</p-multiSelect>
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w72kaw)